# Why is Exception(str()) throwing an exception?

Tags: python, exception

In a CLI application that may or may not be run with a `debug` parameter, I am catching an exception and selectively rethrowing it:

```
try:
    doSomething()
except Exception as e:
    if debug==True:
        raise Exception(str(e))
```

Interestingly, the `raise Exception()` code itself is throwing this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./app.py", line 570, in getSomething
    raise Exception(str(e))
Exception: expected string or buffer
```

Would not `str(e)` return a string? I could only imagine that perhaps it is returning `None` so I tried a general `Exception` (as seen in the code) hoping that it would never be None. Why might `e` not be castable to `string`?

Comment: `str(e) == 'expected string or buffer'`. Your code works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a side note, if you want to re-throw an exception, a stand-alone [`raise`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#raise) statement will do it, which raises the last raised exception. This will give you the actual error as well, rather than just passing the message to `Exception`.

```
try:
    doSomething()
except:  # except by itself catches any exception
         # better to except a specific error though
    if debug:  # use implicit truth check of `if`
        raise  # re-raise the caught exception
```

Also, note that everything can be converted to a string (unless you [explicitly say it can't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17772898/1907098)).

Comment: Thank you! I selected this as the Answer as you do address a way to improve the code as well.

Comment: The lasted raised exception is not specific. A stand alone raise will re-raise the exception currently being handled. If it is out of the except, there is an error.

Comment: @zhangyangyu but even if an exception was raised and then handled before, it is reraised. Take for example [this ideone](http://ideone.com/M0cFF2)

Comment: I tried the code on my Linux, both 2.7.3 and 3.3.2. All failed. I don't know why.@Volatility

Answer (score 4):

I think you are misunderstanding the Exception message.

In your `doSomething`, an exception raised, the exception is `expected string or buffer`. Then you use that string to re-throw an exception. And you do not catch this exception. So, the interpreter stops and print the message.

```
>>> try:
...     raise Exception('expected string or buffer')
... except Exception as e:
...     raise Exception(str(e))
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
Exception: expected string or buffer
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you zhangyangyu. Now that I see how that was happening, it is almost funny!