# Is there a Data Type in Python which cannot be typecast in string

Tags: python, python-2.7

Lets say '`a`' is of some type (which I want to know!)

Doing a thing like:

```
b = str(a)
```

This should favorably raise a `TypeError`

Comment: Note that this is *not* a typecast. The `str` function simply obtains a *string representation* of an object. The string representation doesn't have to be an "equivalent" to the object itself. It isn't a conversion of a value from one type to another. Also note that doing what you are trying to do breaks an implicit assumption that `str(some_object)` never fails. If you aren't interested in implementing your own string representation simply don't overwrite `__str__`, and let the default implementation do its(mostly useless) job.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no builtin Python class that raises a TypeError with `str`, but you could define a custom class:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __str__(self):
        raise TypeError('Can not by stringified')


foo = Foo()
b = str(foo)
```

raises a `TypeError`.